# VS Code update removed extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the following folder I created a new language for VS Code `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\mynewlanguage`

Today I updated VS Code to `v1.17.2`.

After VS code update, this folder doesn't exist anymore. Is it normal? Where should I have created my language? Did I lose all my work?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is normal. The `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions` folder is reserved for extensions that VS Code ships with by default. It appears that this folder is overwritten upon each update, which would clear out any files you put there.

The place where all extensions from the marketplace go (and where you should have put your custom extension) is in `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\.vscode\extensions`.

Chances are high that unless you made a backup of the extension somewhere else, your work is lost.